# Curl failed: Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 5000 after 1002 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Tags: php, curl

i have this code, its works very fine from localserver to online server, but from online server to online server gives me this
Curl failed: Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 5000 after 1002 ms: Couldn't connect to server
any Advice please
Thanks in advance

````
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// require_once('relay.class.php');
// $relay = new relay();

$url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5000/api/table/sfuse1";
// $url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5000/api/table/sfuse1";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
if ($resp === FALSE) {
    die("Curl failed: " . curl_error($curl));
}
// var_dump($resp);
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($resp, true);
// // var_dump($result['Content']);
// foreach($result['Content'] as $v){
//    if($v['code'] == 'MX-MASTER3'){
//       var_dump($v);
//       exit;
//    }
// }
// if($result['Content'])


var_dump($result['Content']);


// foreach($result['Content'] as $row){
//     $name_en = $row['code'];
//     $name_fr =  $row['code'];
//     // $color_code =  $row['code'];
//     $relay->AddColors($name_en,$name_fr,'NULL');
// }

// echo "<script> window.location.href='../../relay.php'</script>"; ?>

code ```
**bold**
*italic*
>quote

       
any advice please
thanks
````

Comment: Ask the providers of the online server where you're running this cURL code, whether they allow outbound connections on port 5000 (or any other ports). Probably a firewall rule is blocking it.

Comment: but i can use it from xamp normal, only online gives me this,
and do you mean from my side or the api server? Thanks

Comment: `but i can use it from xamp`..well clearly your local machine doesn't have the same firewall restrictions, then. Your firewall has nothing to do with XAMPP or PHP.

Comment: `do you mean from my side or the api server`...I mean from the machine which executes the cURL code, as I already explained. Whether you call that your API server or your "my side" I don't know.